# Unable to implement IP White Listing in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling, whitelist

I am doing POC on WSO2 API Manager for one of the project and trying to implement white listing IP for a particular API such that API should not be accessible from any other IP.

I have tried implementing the same using the WSO2 documentation (https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Managing+Throttling) but couldn't do it.

Is it really possible to achieve the above scenario in WSO2 API Manager? If yes, then please guide to implement the same.

Comment: `but couldn't do it` - please elaborate - do you mean you cannot follow the documentation or other IPs are not blocked? What type of security are you using (Application/User)? (if you say no security, I believe some throttling features are not engaged)

Comment: I have followed the documentation but ip white listing is not happening as expected.  The configuration in advance throttling policy is given below:                                                                                 --> Default Limit-200 Units, Time-1 Year                                                                     
--> Invert Condition-On                                                                                          --> Execution Policy- Request Count-0, Time-1 Year

Comment: Yes, I am using OAuth Security for application and client credential grant type is being used.

Comment: Please share your answer on this problem as i am not able to resolve it for past 3 weeks. IS the platform provides this feature or am i doing some mistake while configuration.If anyone attained this IP Whitelisting feature in WSO2 please guide me to do the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to implement IP Whitelisting with WSO2 API-M. 
Usually, after creating an advanced throttling policy as per instructed in the documentation [1], it takes some time to deploy the execution policy. The first few requests from the IPs, that should be blocked, will be passed through. After the execution policy is successfully deployed, accessing from non-whitelisted IP addresses will be blocked.

But, when creating the related conditional group, if the time duration is set to a small duration, i.e. 1 minute, the execution policy will reset every 1 minute. During this resetting time, the requests from the IPs, that should be blocked, will be passed through. This can be avoided by setting a high time duration so that we can have a low frequency of resetting the execution policy. Then there won't be any intermittent passthrough calls from the blocked IP addresses.

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Managing+Throttling#ManagingThrottling-IPWhitelisting

Comment: But the same thing we have tried on WSO2 API manager 2.6 version with distributed set up with the blocking duration as 5 years. But still the rule did not get implemented . We checked the same after 24 hours also. How much time it actually takes to deploy the policy.